# Checkstyle reports LocalFinalVariableNameCheck error on catch-exception parameter

Tags: java, checkstyle, metrics, coding-style

I have an odd issue and I am not sure if it is a problem between two ears or a checkstyle issue.
Running checkstyle 6.2 we are getting both, in jenkins and eclipse this error:

```
LocalFinalVariableNameCheck, Priority: Normal 

Name 'pEx' must match pattern '^l[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$'.
```

and this is the code

```
...
} catch (final XPathExpressionException pEx) {
   throw new ConfigurationException(pEx);
}
```

Why is checkstyle defining a catch block as a local var and not a param?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with the help of Boris I found a solution. It is a change which was incorporated with checkstyle 5.7 like it looks

```
    <module name="LocalFinalVariableName">
        <!-- checkstyle changed to pass exception checks to local vars?!? in version 5.7 -->
        <!-- catch blocks have params => use a different local var -->
        <property name="format" value="^p[a-zA-Z0-9]*$" />
        <property name="tokens" value="PARAMETER_DEF" />
    </module>
    <module name="LocalFinalVariableName">
        <property name="format" value="^l[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$" />
        <property name="tokens" value="VARIABLE_DEF" />
    </module>
    <module name="LocalVariableName">
        <!-- checkstyle changed to pass exception checks to local vars?!? in version 5.7 -->
        <!-- catch blocks have params => use a different local var -->
        <property name="format" value="^p[a-zA-Z0-9]*$" />
        <property name="tokens" value="PARAMETER_DEF" />
    </module>
    <module name="LocalVariableName">
        <property name="format" value="^l[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$" />
        <property name="tokens" value="VARIABLE_DEF" />
    </module>
```

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by @Dongqing, pEx is indeed a local variable, so the check applies here.

One note, though: the default for this rule is `^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$` as specified in the [checkstyle documentation](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_naming.html#Modules) (last version of the tool). The pattern you have as probably been customised to fit some local standard `^l[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$`. So before removing the violation, you should probably make sure the naming pattern is really ok (why defining a custom rule if it does not fit?).

If you really want to get rid of this violation, Checkstyle provides various ways to suppress warnings. You can:

- Use a [suppression XML file](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config.html#SuppressionFilter), that allows you to inhibit a specific rule, on a specific file, for a given range of lines (or even range of columns). That way you don't have to modify the code, but you need to maintain a separated file with all your suppressions.
- Use comments or annotations to disable warnings by adding either a comment or an annotation (e.g. `@SuppressWarnings`) right in the code, where the false-positive is. 
  This must be configured, too. See the link above for more details and examples.

EDIT: This Checkstyle rule also allows you to tune the pattern for variable declaration **or** catch clauses. The following configuration should work for you:

```
<module name="LocalVariableName">
    <property name="format" value="^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$"/>
    <property name="tokens" value="PARAMETER_DEF"/>
</module>
```

Here you specify a very tolerant pattern for violations in catch clauses only. Variable declaration should not be affected and still be checked for the original pattern.

Comment: Boris, thx for the answer. Regarding usage of rules. We like to use the rule for local vars. But for catch-blocks it does not fit. So we search for an option to disable the localVar and localFinalVar check for the Exception in a generic way by a suppressions file or by configuring the rule properly to skip catch-blocks. We cannot find neither an answer

Comment: @cilap see my edit. You can tune the rule to match only catch block for a given pattern.

Comment: Hi Boris, I have posted the full answer. And your hint helped to find it. thx

Answer (score 2):

try {} catch (){} is a **statement** not a method call. so pEx is a local var not a parameter

Comment: good point thx.
Do you have an idea how to remove the checkstyle rule from exceptions?